# Habanero pepper sunburned?

Tags: peppers, sunlight, habaneros

So it's my first time growing a Pepper and what i noticed is that one fruit started getting little bit dark on one side and then almost all other fruits also got dark. Now i am thinking that is related to the sun/light as only window side got dark, but i am not sure, especially since i grow it indoors and direct sunlight only hits in the evening through the window for up to 2 hours a day.

Some pictures:

[image: "Burned" side of the same fruit]
"Burned" side of the first fruit to ripen

[image: Other "Burned" fruits]
Other "Burned" fruits

So my question is, what is this, should i do something about it or is it something normal?

Answer (score 1):

Completely normal, sweetie!! The colors change as they ripen into the dark reds.